# Laravel Echo Server giving Error Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io

i am trying to install Laravel Echo Server on Laravel 5.5 with the help of thie Article
https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-echo-server-how-to-24d5778ece8b

All things is going right but when i

```
laravel-echo-server start
```

Error comes with

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
```

i install laravel 5.6 but still i face the same error

Thanks in advance who can guide me how can i handle this error

Comment: Looks like you didn't install redis

Comment: but in Article he did't

Comment: Sure *he* did, it notes that in the *Requirements*. also the error is clearly saying ioredis cant connect to redis port on localhost.

Comment: same error after npm install redis

Comment: that's going to install a node javascript client, you need the server https://redis.io/topics/quickstart

Comment: are you sure we need this node javascript client

Comment: no, you only need the server.. also redis is only used for cross clients.. if your not doing that its not needed.. you should also read the socket.io docs.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis already have

Comment: but using this composer require predis/predis we already install this

Comment: yes i am going to use Socket.IO by reading this article 
https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d
but problem is laravel echo server is giving error

Comment: geeer ;p predis is a php redis client! ;p you still need the redis-server. Its much like *mysql*, you have a gazzillion ways to connect to it (clients) but you still need to install the server.

Comment: by Installing this 
https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads now the error is close , Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Redis is not installed or the Redis server is not running.

> - Download and install the server from https://redis.io/
> - And then run the service with "redis-server".

After that you can smoothly run "laravel-echo-server start"

Answer (score 0):

make sure that redis listen on 127.0.0.1:6379.
look at /etc/redis/redis.conf, the line where is indicated "bind ....". make sure it's "bind 127.0.0.1" otherwise go to your laravel-echo-server.json and change databaseConfig: {redis: {port: "6379", host: "..."}}.
"..." indicating what is marked in redis.conf

Answer (score 0):

For those using laravel sail (I had the same problem but redis is already installed in the container), you can do what [De Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55392436/14663720) said in `laravel-echo-server.json` :

```json
"databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "redis"
        },
        ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have install radis server

> sudo apt install redis-server